# Using ARM microcontrollers on breadboard

Tags: microcontroller, breadboard

There seem to be no (or very few) ARM MCU's that can be fitted directly in a breadboard (DIP packages).

What are the options? Is it possible to somehow use SMD packaged MCU's on a breadboard, or is the only option just buying a development board? Do you have any good recommendations on that front?

Comment: there's the Teensy range.

Comment: Some of the LPC 800 series of Cortex M0s from NXP are in DIP packages.

Comment: I'm using 8-bit atmegas right now, but the point is that through whole components seem to be on the way out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use adapter boards for SMD packages:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks just like i probably need. Are the connections reliable? Is there anything i should watch out for if i get one of those?

Comment: LQFP32 is easy to hand-solder. You should put bypass capacitors as close to VDD as possible (see the two SMD caps at corners). There also are SMD pads for capacitors or pull-down resistors on the bottom side of the board.

Comment: You also install zero-ohm resistors at the pin(s) that actually are ground.

Comment: Thanks for all the info. One other question -- are there any prototype boards (like a perfboard but for smd) or anything that I can prototype smd components on? That is, if I DON'T use an adapter as shown above, are are my options in prototyping surface mount device circuits? How is it normally done? And how is it done in a professional context?

Comment: start with kicad and oshpark.  very easy to use, good results.   graduate to altium (is there a free/hobby altium?  I dont know) and contract manufacturers that do the board and assembly and supply parts etc.  I stopped using perfboards and other similar things a long time ago now.

Comment: Depending on how you prototype you may still desire to have breakout boards for the various components, prototype with those, then create an integrated pcb with all the components, depends on the size of the projects as to whether it makes sense to stop at breakout boards or just prototype on a pcb